# I have ever had is/was?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

Let's say you are asked about the most dangerous sport you have tried. And you say:

> "the most dangerous sport that I have ever tried **is/was** skateboarding.''

Which one is the correct preposition?

Comment: John,  you can't have a sport: you do a sport. The subject is singular, so the verb would be also. What preposition?? Do you mean verb?

Comment: Hmm, right, I'll change it into 'do' then...

Comment: Using "ever" indicates past time including the present moment, so you can't use past tense.

Comment: Is my answer grammatical now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example is in present perfect tense so "is" would be the right choice. If you were speaking about the past, you don`t do any dangerous sports anymore,  "was" would be appropriate.